# gcc -O1 optimization slower than -O0

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, fortran

I've been rewriting a program that is a mix of Fortran and C, which is around 10k lines of random particle simulation. However, I recently realised that Release mode was running a *lot* slower than Debug.

Debug  (-O0): 23 seconds. Release(-O1 or -O2): 43 seconds. For a small test run.

This only changes when the C optimization settings are changed within Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->GCC C Compiler->Optimization Level, and is unaffected by the GNU Fortran compiler settings.

Looking into this, it seems that -O1 and -O2 run slowly, while -O0 runs a lot faster. Even with all optimization flags set manually (from [GCC Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)), it still runs faster than -O1.

It may be that running in Release causes different results which cause extra computations to be made (values being outside of their expected ranges etc.), would this be likely? And if so would it be possible to change the behaviour back to the original Debug settings?

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you need more information to help.

Chris.

Edit: System Information:

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- GCC version 4.8.1
- Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers, Juno SR2

Comment: Without knowing the code, the compiler version and platform, nor how you measure, that's quite difficult to answer...

Comment: You will have to profile and find the problematic part of code, otherwise no-one can know.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with optimizations for size (`-Os`)? If *that* is slower than `-O0`, your program is seriously suspect.

Comment: Okay it seems that -Os still runs slower than -O0, and the extra time seems to be spent in a single function which has 5x more calls than usual in the optimised code (using gprof from the Linux Tools Eclipse plugins). Will post back when I have a definitive solution. Thanks.

Comment: You do not have to come with the *definitive* solution. If you edit the question some people may be able to help you and those who downvoted it could revert the downvotes.

Comment: It seems to be a problem changing the results of the code, creating a different program flow. Will update when I actually know what's happening.

Comment: Updated with answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it turns out that this occurs for version 4.8.1 of gcc, but not the later versions (is fixed with 4.8.3). For both the equivalent C and Fortran codes, using -O1 or higher caused the compiler to incorrectly optimise the code.

To simplify the code, the incorrect result occurs from the lines:

```
a = b - c;
c = c + a;
```

Which, if computed normally would be `c = b + (c - c);`, reducing to `c = b;`.
But seems to instead be calculated as `c = c + (b - c);`, which is calculated normally.

This creates a very slight inaccuracy (-0.0999999978 compared to -0.1000000015).
In this case, this resulted in a loop that would have run 2 times, to run 1500 times, and for this to happen over 500 times across the run.

The way it was (accidentally) fixed, was to force the compiler to calculate `a = b - c` before running the `c = c + a`. This can be done by `printf("%f\n",a);`, or `c = c + 0` between calculating `a` and `c` (both seemed to work). Note, this line does not ever have to run. You can put this into a `if` statement that is never true (e.g. `if (a == INT_MAX)`) but not somewhere the compiler *knows* it will never run (e.g. `if (false)`).

At least this is my, and my supervisors, current thoughts on the matter. Still not exactly sure what part of the optimisation causes this, or what fixed it in the most recent versions, but I hope this can be helpful for someone else and save them a week of confusion.

Thanks for the help anyway. - Chris.

Comment: Yes, although floating-point numbers are often *called* "reals", they are not. Operations that would be commutative and associative on reals may not be on floats. `A + B - A != B` in general for floats. `gcc` has a `-fassociative-math` flag to allow the compiler to reorder expressions *as if they were associative*. This obviously impacts precision, though not necessarily negatively.